# Calculating and improving time & memory complexity (Java)

Tags: java, complexity-theory

```
private static int Sum (int[] a, int from, int to){
    int total=0;
    for (int i=from; i <= to; i++)
        res += a[i];
    return total;
}

public static int Method3 (int []a){
    int temp=0;
    for (int i=0; i <= a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j <= a.length; j++)
        {
            int c = Sum(a,i,j);
            if (c%3 == 0)
            {
                if (j-i+1 > temp)
                temp = j-i+1;
             }
         }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

The purpose of Method3 method is finding the longest combination of a given array numbers' , so that the sum of the numbers of the combination can be divided by 3 without remainder. 
   I'm now trying to figure out the time and memory complexity of the Method3 method , and then my   purpose is to learn how to improve it to the maximum.

My assumption is :
   the first two loops in Method3 result in time complexity of O(n^2) because it's repeated 
(n + (n-1) + ... +1) times , which equals to [n(n+1)]/2 => (1/2)n^2+(1/2)n => O(n^2).
BUT, we also have the Sum method, which is nested within both of the loops in Method3, and its worst-case complexity can only be O(n) - since it's the biggest possible gap between i and j(or a.length in other words)
So therefore , I think the final time complexity for Method3 is : n^2 * n = n^3. Is that right?
Now , regarding memory complexity , I'm really confused. My assumption is that it's O(1), because there are only integer variable in this program ,that hold one field.

Now the next question, how do I make it more efficient? How do I even approach to something like this? and finally, how can I know that the complexity I've reached is the best possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This is off topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code.

Comment: I'm sorry. But can I at least get help regarding calculating complexity? I'm not sure my answer was correct. I doubt it is as a matter of fact...
Thanks.

Comment: This does not throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: I can recommend this great introduction into the wonderful world of Design and Analysis of Algorithms: https://www.coursera.org/course/algo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, time complexity is O(n^3).
And yes, space complexity is O(1). The only space used is constant number of indices.

A way to make your algorithm more efficient and shorten the amount of comparisons is to **reverse your inside for loop**.  Right now, you are basically checking every possible combination of i and j. For example, for indices 1, 2, 3, 4. you are checking 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4.

Instead, you can start with **j = a.length()-1**. That way, you are starting with the 'longest combination' with your current i. As soon as a combination works (meaning if the combination satisfies the Sum(1, i, j)%3 == 0 requirement), you don't have to check all the other j values, and you can jump to the next i value.

Your Sum method is fine the way it is.

EDIT:

The result is still going to be an O(n^3) worst case time complexity. but in reality, can it potentially make your code faster? Yes.(definitely) 
Since you have three iterations, the worst case is always going to be N^3, though.

Comment: Thank you very much !
I'm sorry I cant vote up , I don't have enough reputation

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I added another edit. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: If I understood you correctly , what you mean to do is just changing the inner loop in Method3 to : 
for (int j=a.length-1; j>0; j--)
Right?

But in that case, (unless it's the best-case) ,the complexity is still the same , no?
Or maybe that's the whole thing? In the original program no matter what - the complexity was always n^3.

But now, it's n^3 in the worst-case, but O(n) in the best?

Comment: It's still going to be N^3 worst case time complexity, but in reality, it can potentially make your code faster. But yes, since your have 3 iterations, the worst case is always going to be N^3

Comment: Will it be just N in the best case or O(1)?
Also, how can I know what the average case would be? Does it even matter in reality?
And final question, when you make a new algorithm or just program a certain solution to a problem , how do you know it has the optimal complexity and you can stop thinking of a better one?
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: @BinaryVeil The only way to know if an algorithm is optimal is by mathematical proof. There is no easy shortcut for this. For some algorithms it may be really easy, for some algorithms it may be impossible. Calculating the avarage case also requires mathematical analysis. Basically, these questions are a little bit too broad for this format.

Comment: Thanks. 
In our example here, Steve offered a much better solution, where the best case is O(1) (or N, not sure, correct me if I'm wrong please) , and N^3 in the worst case.
Someone at the university told me he managed to think of something that is N^2 . 
What is considered better? constant N^2 , or a complexity of the range of O(1) to O(N^3) ?
That's by the way why I've asked about the average complexity.

Comment: Actually.. if the best-case is O(1) and the worst-case is O(n^3), then the average is (1+n^3)/2 => 1/2 n^3 => n^3 . Am I wrong?

Comment: The average case is NOT best-case plus worst-case divided by 2. It requires amortized analysis. Please see below:

Comment: Also, if your friend's solution is a constant O(n^2), then his is definitely better.

Comment: When formally comparing algorithms, what matters is the big-O worst case time complexity.